# How to resolve the dilemma of saying "accoucher de de telles histoires"?

Tags: prépositions, articles, partitif, de

> Seules des bardes pourraient accoucher **de de** telles histoires !

Am I correct in thinking that:

1. "accoucher de" in the sense of "come up with (an idea)" needs to be accompanied by "de"?
2. in order to express the idea of "some such stories", you cannot omit "de" from "de telles histoires"?

So the question is: how to handle the *duplicate* use of the "de"?

Comment: Definitely a typo, there should only be one *de*. Where did you find that sentence?

Comment: Oh, I was trying to translate a sentence from English, and I didn't know how to handle the two consecutive "de"s. In such a case, is it necessary to omit one of the two and keep only one? Merci.

Comment: My bad. Then it's an excellent question! Will try to answer.

Comment: Yep, you'll never read or hear "de de". If I am correct it's the same for "to to" in english…

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Seules des bardes pourraient **accoucher de** telles histoires.

C'est **l'article partitif qui disparaît**.

Après la préposition **de** on omet **l'article indéfini pluriel** et **l'article partitif**. En effet les contractions :

- de+des ; de+du ; de+ de la ; de+de l'

sont impossibles, et on ne fait pas la répétition non plus. On peut expliquer cela en disant que c'est pour éviter la répétiion du son /d/. Ceci est inné chez les francophones et c'est une faute qu'il ne font jamais, on ne l'enseigne comme règle que dans l'enseignement du français langue étrangère (FLE). Par exemple, [voir cette page](http://www.patenotte.name/Aix/Ecriture/Feuilles_aides_pedagogiques/articles_leur_suppression.html).

Voici quelques exemples ou je fais ressortir la disparition de l'article (partitif ou pluriel) :

- J'ai vu **des gens** mais j'ai vu **beaucoup de** gens.
- Il y a **des fleurs** sur la pelouse mais la pelouse est **remplie de** fleurs.
- Elle a eu **des jumeaux** mais elle a **accouché de** jumeaux.
- Je veux **de l'eau** mais je veux **plein d'** eau j'ai **envie d'** eau.

  ---

The verb is *accoucher de* and plural indefinite article *des* and partitive articles *du/de la/des* are omitted when following preposition *de*. This is to avoid repetition of the /d/ sound. French natives do not repeat it by instinct (it is a mistake they never make) but it is taught as a rule in FLE courses (Français Langue Étrangère).
See [here](http://bit.ly/29X41zm) (2.3.2 Omission of plural indefinite *des* after the prepostion *de*) 
and [here](http://bit.ly/2ajToK1) (4.1.1 Omission of the article after prepositions).

Comment: Est-ce que l'article partitif disparaît vraiment ? *J'ai vu beaucoup de la pièce mais je suis parti avant la fin.* Dans les exemples donnés, il me semble qu'il ne s'agit pas de partitifs : *un peu de citron* (massif) contraste avec *un peu du citron* (partitif).

Comment: @GAMPUB les deux cas, pluriel des et partitif,  sont présents dans mes exemples, je n'ai pas jugé utile de distinguer, ça ne change rien. Par contre si ta remarque émet le doute sur disparition de la préposition ou de l'article, je donne la règle telle qu'elle est toujours enseignée aux apprenants de FLE. C'est une règle généralement admise par les spécialistes.

Comment: Dans les trois premiers exemples, il s'agit clairement de pluriels: je n'ai pas vu une partie des gens, il n'y a pas une partie des fleur, elle n'a pas eu une partie des jumeaux. Le quatrième est bien un partitif pour la première phrase mais pas pour la seconde... Les règles généralement admises par les *spécialistes* sont parfois différentes de celles établies par les spécialistes : pour les partitifs, voir les exemples donnés dans le commentaire précédent.

Comment: @GAMPUB Dans « un peu du citron », il y a un article défini : un peu de ce fruit-là. Si c'était un article partitif (un peu de pulpe ou de jus) qui viennent d'un ou plusieurs fruits), on dirait « un peu de citron ».

Comment: @Gilles Je suis tout à fait d'accord, dans un partitif, contrairement à un massif, il y a un ensemble dont on prend une part. Il y a une différence très claire entre *j'ai vu beaucoup de la pièce* (partitif) et *j'ai vu beaucoup de pièces* (indéfini pluriel), la différence entre *un peu du citron* (partitif) et *un peu de citron* (massif) est du même ordre, dans le deuxième cas, il n'y a pas de partie mais une masse indéfinie. Si on ne fait pas de distinction entre massif et partitif alors on peut dire que *un peu de citron* est partitif.

Comment: @GAMPUB Dans « beaucoup de pièces », *de* est un article partitif. Dans « beaucoup de la pièce », *de* est une préposition et *la* est un article défini. Dans « un peu du citron », *du* n'est pas un article partitif, c'est la préposition *de* contractée avec l'article défini *le*. J'ai l'impression que tu t'emmêles les pinceaux, soit dans l'analyse des phrases soit dans la terminologie grammaticale.

Comment: @Gilles, en français, les groupes prépositionnels ne forment jamais de bons sujets grammaticaux : aucun sujet de verbe ne peut commencer par une préposition. Néanmoins, *de la farine est tombée par terre* est une phase grammaticale comme *du pain se trouve sur la planche*. Dans *de pièces*, *de* contient au moins une préposition et *de pièces* ne peut jamais être le sujet d'un verbe, pas plus que *d'eau*.